# how does django assign the foreign key when using the create method of a related object manager?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

How does Django assign the foreign key when using the `create` method of a related object manager?

I'm asking because when I create my own `create` method, the foreign key is not set automatically.

Here is an example:

```
class ModelAQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        print('create:')
        print(kwargs)
        return super().create(**kwargs)

    def create_with_other_options(self, **kwargs):
        print('create_with_other_options:')
        print(kwargs)
        return self.create(**kwargs)

class ModelABaseManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True    

ModelAManager = ModelABaseManager.from_queryset(ModelAQuerySet)

class ModelA(models.Model):
    objects = ModelAManager()
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='modela_set')
```

When I use the methods:

```
>>> u = User.object.get(...)
>>> a1 = u.modela_set.create() # it works, user is set automatically
create:
{..., 'user': <User: id:1 email:"...">}

>>> a2 = u.modela_set.create_with_other_options() # it does not work, user is not set automatically
create_with_other_options:
{}
IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this on your 5th line:

```
return super(ModelAQuery, self).create(**kwargs)
```